# Re filling out ESTA - On the form do I say yes to transit or no?

Tags: esta

Re filling out ESTA - I am flying into the US staying 2 days then flying onto Rome tthen returning 6 weeks later for 4 nights then flying home to NZ. On the form do I say yes to transit or no?

Answer (score 11):

You're staying two days in the country, so that's not a transit.  You're exiting the airport (I assume you're not staying two days in the airport!) and visiting the US.

[From the ESTA help page](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#ta8):

> **Do nationals or citizens of countries that participate in the Visa
>   Waiver Program require travel authorization if they are only
>   transiting the United States en route to another country?**
>
> Eligible
>   nationals or citizens of countries that participate in the Visa Waiver
>   Program require either a travel authorization or a visa to transit the
>   United States. If a traveler is only planning to transit through the
>   United States en route to another country, when he or she completes
>   the travel authorization application in ESTA, the traveler should
>   select "Yes" to the question "Is your travel to the US occurring in
>   transit to another country?".

Comment: If you're staying 2 days at the airport do you put Yes or No?

Answer (score 1):

if you're stupid like me... i read the answer as 'not a transit' incorrectly.

**Yes** = you're staying in the airport and moving on to somewhere else

**No** = you're actually going into the country and staying over in a hotel etc.

So if your going the USA for a holiday select NO and fill out the extra info.

Comment: It can still be a transit even if you stay in a hotel overnight and get a plane the next day. The US does not require transiting passengers to stay in the airport. But if you actually are on holiday in the US, then it is "No" not a transit.