# Applying for Esta

Tags: usa, canada, esta

I am an Italian citizen. In few weeks I will fly from Copenhagen to New York, I will stay there 3 or 4 days and then my plan is to go to Toronto for a couple of weeks and then fly back to Europe.

Now I'm doing the application for the ESTA, but I am not sure what to answer to the following question:

> Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country?

Technically yes, but I will stay stay for some days in the U.S. . What should I answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should answer no, you are not doing a transit, but a multiple destination trip. US is not a transit point for you.

Check here anyways
[enter link description here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45516/re-filling-out-esta-on-the-form-do-i-say-yes-to-transit-or-no) -- your question is a duplicate.

Comment: But they ask me to put a U.S. contact of information.. so I guess I should book some hostel or airbnb before do that..

Comment: Yes, you should do that in advance

Comment: Actually I've noticed that I could also write "UNKNOWN". I did that. I hope they will accept my application...

Comment: @Onil90 and? Did they accept it? You'll need an address for your customs form, which you'll get on the plane and fill out before you present yourself for immigration inspection. The address should be the place where you'll spend your first night in the US.

Comment: @phoog They haven't reply me yet.. :/